# How can I delete a webhook in discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

I want to create a `&imitate [user] [sentence]` command in discord.js, and I want to delete the webhook when it's finished with the command. I have this code:

```
message.channel.createWebhook("Webhook Test", "https://images.app.goo.gl/2rvCG9hndnTYbQqU9")
.then(webhook => webhook.edit({channel: message.channel})
.then(wbhk => wbhk.send('Testing message'))
.then(wb => wb./*What do I put here to delete the webhook?*/).catch(console.error)
```

I was looking around for hours and couldn't find anything about this except for the discord.js docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete a [Webhook](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Webhook), you would use [`Webhook.delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Webhook?scrollTo=delete):

```js
message.channel.createWebhook("Webhook Test", "https://images.app.goo.gl/2rvCG9hndnTYbQqU9")
  .then(webhook => webhook.edit({channel: message.channel})
  .then(webhook => {
    return webhook.send('Testing message').then(message => webhook); // returns the webhook, rather than the message to the next .then call
  })
  .then(webhook => webhook.delete()).catch(console.error)
```

Comment: Not sure why you suddenly needed the curly braces when you still just `return`, but have my upvote :)

Comment: I just like putting braces around everything :p. Glad I could help!